# Read Json data C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following method in My contorller

```
public JsonResult Data()
{
    return Json(details
        .Select(c => new { Height = c.Height, Width = c.Width })
        .Distinct(),
      JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am reading it data as below

```
public void ReadData()
{
  var result = controller.Data() as JsonResult;
  var model = result.Data;
}
```

How do i cast **var model in ReadData** correctly?

Comment: do you want to deserialize data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonResult data will be iterated and serialized during `jsonResult.ExecuteResult` call, but if you just want json data that it will produce - you can manually use the same json serializer that `JsonResult` uses. So it will be like this:

```
public void ReadData()
{
    var result = controller.Data() as JsonResult;
    var model = result.Data;
    JavaScriptSerializer scriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = scriptSerializer.Serialize(model);
}
```

Comment: Using Newtonsoft Json would be a better choice. For many complex types it performs better.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing `System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator<<>f__AnonymousType2<string,string>>` because that's exactly what you return: an enumerable of an anonymous type with two string properties.

You can iterate over that:

```
var model = result.Data;
foreach (var dimension in model)
{
    int h = dimension.Height;
    int w = dimension.Width;
}
```

However, you don't want to go around a JSON serialization and deserialization roundtrip if the API method is in the same project.

Either introduce a concrete type (as opposed to an anonymous type) and change the return type for the API controller:

```
public class Dimension
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Dimension> Data()
{
        return details.Select(c => new Dimension { Height = c.Height, Width = c.Width }).Distinct();
}
```

Or put the logic in its own class:

```
public class DimensionGetter
{
    public IEnumerable<Dimension> GetDimensions()
    {
         return details.Select(c => new Dimension { Height = c.Height, Width = c.Width }).Distinct();
    }
}
```

And call that class from both methods:

```
public JsonResult Data()
{
    return Json(new DimensionGetter.GetDimensions(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public void ReadData()
{
    var model = new DimensionGetter.GetDimensions();
}
```

Comment: That's nice. Care sharing which error specifically?

Answer (score 0):

you can manually use the same json serializer that JsonResult uses. So it will be like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer scriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = scriptSerializer.Serialize(model);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

   public void ReadData()
   {
      var result = controller.Data() as JsonResult;
      var model = result.Data;

      JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializerObject = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      Response.Write(javaScriptSerializerObject.Serialize(model));
   }
```

Comment: It won't work properly, as you are passing `JsonResult` itself to serializer instead of value of `Data` property. So it will serialize all `JsonResult` properties too instead of just one

Answer (score -1):

I think `JavaScriptSerializer()` and `Serialize` will do the Job